# How long is the usual time for an article in production checklist phase at Springer?

Tags: publications, journals

I sent an article to Springer. After two months, it is in the checklist phase for production. How long does it take for the article to be printed and do I need to email the editor?

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/55665/what-does-the-typical-workflow-of-a-journal-look-like-how-should-i-interpret-a This might be a better link, since "production checklist" suggests the article is past acceptance.